# Android - layout error:106 width:0 ellipsizedWidth:0

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

While I am debugging and testing my Android App, it displays all the time inside DDMS the following warning:

layout error:106 width:0 ellipsizedWidth:0

It keeps repeating the same warning even while connecting my mobile and testing it there.

Basically what I have done is changed the transition between my activities to iPhone Style (activity moves aside and another activity comes in place).

I got the code for that online, but basically it's very straight forward, you just create an xml file for the transition and call the following method when you want to call another activity:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);
```

Now my App is working great and also performing very fast, but I am afraid because there's like tons of similar warnings in the DDMS, so I don't know if this is going to affect the performance of either my App or the mobile device where the App is installed in the future.

Below is a screenshot from DDMS

[image: a Eclipse Error]
<sub>(source: [cleverservice.net](http://www.cleverservice.net/stackoverflow/eclipse_error_17_07_2012.jpg))</sub>

![Eclipse Error][1]

Comment: Can you provide us with the code where the error occured?

Comment: Well it's not clear in Eclipse. Even though it says "layout error", this is not affecting the App since it's running without any problems. It seems more like a warning but I'm just wondering if it hurts or not... Any ideas?